# llamar el metodo de una instancia desde otra instancia

Tags: javascript

necesito llamar un método de una instancia con atributos propios desde otra instancia

```
class clase{
    constructor(nombre, otraInstancia){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.otraInstancia = otraInstancia;
    }
    
    funcion(){
        alert(this.nombre);
    }
```

intente

```
   llamar(){
       window[this.otraInstancia].funcion();
   }
}

instancia = new clase("instancia1", instancia2;
instancia2 = new clase("instancia2", instancia);

instancia.llamar();
```

cuando intento llamar la funcion llamar obtengo "llamar undefined"

PD. tengo que llamar un método dentro de la clases que hace cambios al html y al css. Cuando se active el evento click que también esta dentro de la misma clase quiero que se active el método que cambia el css y html en una instancia, desde otra instancia hermana de la misma clase. perdon si esta revuelto.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor la duda, no queda del todo clara?

Comment: Es decir ¿Al método `llamar` lo quieres invocar por cada instancia hecha pero con argumentos propios para que el alert salga con un valor distinto?

Comment: no necesariamente pero si
en esencia quiero que se pueda llamar un método de la instancia.
ha veces necesito que cambien cosas en el html y están vinculadas a la instancia y necesito poder activarlas desde otra instancia

Comment: @BetaM tengo que llamar un método dentro de la clases que hace cambios al html y al css cuando se active el evento click que también esta dentro de la misma clase quiero que se active el método que cambia el css y html en una instancia desde otra instancia hermana de la misma clase.

perdon si esta revuelto.

Comment: Todos estos detalles que me platicas deben ir en tu pregunta, para que la o las personas que te ayuden tengan contexto completo de lo que pretendes lograr

Comment: @betaM esta bien lo editare

Comment: @betaM alguna idea de como puedo lograrlo?

Comment: Saludos. Revisa lo siguiente; el momento que haces `instancia = new clase("instancia1", instancia2);` (te falta `)` de cierre lo que pusiste, revisa no este tu código así); 'instancia2' no existe, es decir es `undefined`.Una forma de corroborarlo es (si no me equivoco) así como esta tu código en vez de `instancia.llamar();` hacer `instancia2.llamar();` y que en `llamar` tengas `this.otraInstancia.funcion();` (el `windows[this.otraInstancia]` no veo donde lo declaras/asignas).

Answer (score 1):

Por favor, para próximas consultas detalla mejor la cuestión.

El problema que le veo es que "instancia2" no está definida cuando creas el objeto "instancia", si por ejemplo decides pasarle un segundo parámetro nulo en el constructor de "instancia", a la hora de llamar a "llamar()" fallará pues es una método que no existe de un método nulo.

Espero haberte servido.